# How to connect Azure App service to Azure VM?

Tags: selenium, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-vm

I have a Selenium Java project which is a web services project. This project has 3 web services.
this project is hosted on azure app service. But Azure app service does not have its own Virtual machine where I can install chrome. 
I am very much new to all this. Can anyone help me in linking azure app service to an azure VM where I can install a chrome browser and run automation test cases?

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the VM is allowed to access external webste, of course you can install a chrome browser and run automation test cases.

If the VM is not allowed to access external website, and you want to access Azure App service internally. You can link them via the vnet.

Reference:

[Configure VNet Integration with your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#configure-vnet-integration-with-your-app)